# How to pass additional data to getserversideprops from another page in Nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I want to pass `projectID` from the previous page`(/projects`) to the (`/project/[projectName]`). Therefore, in order to fetch a project details, i have to fire an API endpoint with `projectID.`

What is the right way to pass projectID from the previous page and also how to access it in the `getServersideProps` method.

In the `/project/[projectName]` page,

```
export async function getServerSideProps(){
// Here i want to access the projectID sent from the previous page
const data = await fetchData();
return {
    props: data,
  };
}
```

`Query/param` prop will have access to the projectName but not projectID.

Answer (score 0):

As serverSideProps will run each time the page is loaded, you can't pass data from one page to another.

What you can do, is either pass data using useContext or if it's general data that you are going to use on all your pages you can fetch it directly on to the _app.js and pass it for all the children components.

This is an [example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-context-api) using useContext.

This are the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) fetching on the _app.js. (check the commented code)

You can even combine both techniques and set the data on the _app.js and the consume it on any page or component.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data from any page to other page via simple Query/params, when redirecting the user why not just append the `projectId` in query like this
`/projects/[projectName]?projectId=1234`, now in your `getServerSideProps` access the query object to get this variable.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const id = context.query.projectId 
    console.log(context.query)
    //also see console.log(context.params)

}
```